# Advantages of non preemptive kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, process

**The Question is still unresolved since the duplicate answer was wrong (has a false claim as I explained in my last comment)**

I have seen the following question:

> Why the first Linux developers chose to implement a non preemptive kernel?
>
> **Hint:** Linux was developed in the 90s, where personal computers mostly had only one CPU core. Which advantage non preemptive kernel
> provides on s single core computer and why this advantage decreases in
> multi core?

I am still confused why a non preemptive kernel will give any advantage, any idea or help is appreciated.

Comment: Please Note the duplicate answers "Why the first Linux developers chose to implement a non preemptive kernel?" but doesn't answer the advantage I am talking about...

Comment: From my answer to the linked question, “On single-CPU systems, pre-emption is still useful because it allows events to be processed with shorter reaction times; however, it also results in lower throughput (since the kernel spends time switching tasks).” The advantage of a non-preemptive kernel is higher throughput. (It’s also simpler to write...)

Comment: well you said: "however, it also results in lower throughput (since the kernel spends time switching tasks)" which means the advantage of non preemptive kernel is maximal throughput. I got this #But# you didn't explain how this advantage is lower in multi core CPU which is what the op asked for... @StephenKitt

Comment: I tried to: “Preemption allows any given CPU, in a single or multiple CPU system, to switch to another task more rapidly. The limiting factor on multi-CPU systems isn’t preemption, it’s locks, big or otherwise: any time code takes a lock, it means that another CPU can’t start performing the same action.” A non-preemptive kernel gives higher throughput, but multi-CPU systems are limited by locking (which isn’t a concern on a single-CPU system).

Comment: @StephenKitt To sum it up I think writing "On single-CPU systems, preemption is still useful because it allows events to be processed with shorter reaction times; however, it also results in lower throughput (since the kernel spends time switching tasks)" is incorrect, since if all processes were in user space then the kernel can and will do preemption, thus it will spend time on switching tasks in both cases thus lower throughputs in both cases and not only in one as you said.

Comment: User-space preemption is the base scenario in the comparison: non-preemptible and preemptible kernels both preempt user-space. Thus, compared to a non-preemptible kernel, a preemptible kernel spends more time switching contexts, since it has more preemption points, and therefore results in a system with overall lower throughput (but better interactive response).

Comment: You just said: "non-preemptible and preemptible kernels both preempt user-space." then why you made this false claim: "Thus, compared to a non-preemptible kernel, a preemptible kernel spends more time switching contexts" if nothing ran in kernel space then both will have the same exact throughput. They only differ in kernel space so your claim in wrong in this case. @StephenKitt

Comment: How do you ensure that nothing runs in kernel space? Even switching between processes (“user-space”) involves running in kernel space. The only way to avoid running in kernel space is to isolate CPUs and use them for a single task; but you always need at least one CPU in the system which will take care of kernel duties.

Comment: (And processes run in kernel-space any time they issue a system call.)

Comment: Even switching between processes (“user-space”) involves running in kernel space that's right but in such case both kernel types take same time, this task can't be splited in preemptible kernel so no extra time so no lower throughput. Again my point is your claim isn't correct in All cases. @StephenKitt

Comment: Even if context switches take the same time in both types of kernel, they happen more often on preemptible kernels, so you end up with a reduction in throughput.